# How can I use ruby on rails within my css using a style tag?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a blog using ruby on rails and when I create a post using active admin. I made it give me the choice of selecting a color. How can I use my `post.color` within my style tag of the background-color of my header in show.html.erb?

Like to github repo: https://github.com/pauldesign/blog_0.2

Comment: Add code related to your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<div style="color:<%= @post.color %>"></div>
```

Lokking at your question in the answer above. In your `Post` controller, show action, make sure you have something like this:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

Now in your `Project/show.html.erb` you can access the value like so:

```
<div style="color:<%= @post.color %>"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if your "post.color" contains a color code or a valid html color name, then you should only need to do something like

```
<div style="color:<%= @post.color %>"></div>
```

ofcourse, you have to send that from your controller

Comment: How do I send it from my controller?

Comment: @post = Post.first to send the first, you should have a way to know wich one you want to send